# Pulling stock information using pandas datareader

Tags: python, pandas, stock, datareader

I am using pandas datareader to pull stock information for a given range of dates. For example:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2018,3,26)
end = dt.datetime(2018,3,29)

web.DataReader('IBM','yahoo', start, end).reset_index()
```

This returns the following dataframe for IBM:

[image]

This contains the information I am looking for, but I would like to automatically iterate through multiple stock tickers (instead of manually changing the stock ticker). Ideally I could loop this code through a list of desired stock tickers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another way, creating your dataframe directly:

```
tickers = ['IBM','AAPL']

df = pd.concat([web.DataReader(ticker,'morningstar', start, end) for ticker in tickers]).reset_index()
```

Which returns:

```
  Symbol       Date   Close      High     Low     Open    Volume
0    IBM 2018-03-26  153.37  153.6570  150.28  151.210   4103904
1    IBM 2018-03-27  151.91  154.8697  151.16  153.950   3883745
2    IBM 2018-03-28  152.52  153.8600  151.89  152.070   3664826
3    IBM 2018-03-29  153.43  153.8900  151.08  153.070   3419959
4   AAPL 2018-03-26  172.77  173.1000  166.44  168.070  37541236
5   AAPL 2018-03-27  168.34  175.1500  166.92  173.680  40922579
6   AAPL 2018-03-28  166.48  170.0200  165.19  167.250  41668545
7   AAPL 2018-03-29  167.78  171.7500  166.90  167.805  38398505
```

Comment: I dont get the symbol column. I only get from Date to Volume columns

Answer (score 3):

I think that this might be what you are looking for.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2018,3,26)
end = dt.datetime(2018,3,29)
tickers = ['IBM', 'FB']
data = {}
for t in tickers:
   data[t] = web.DataReader(t,'morningstar', start, end).reset_index()
```